# invalid resource directory name values-de-DE (Braintree sdk)

Tags: braintree

I downloaded official braintree library (PayPal)

I imported it as a usual library and i got this error:

```
invalid resource directory name values-de-DE
```

The default folder name was "values-de_DE" and i read in stack that underscope is not allowed so i changed it, but the error remains still.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource folders were incorrectly named, we've released 1.2.5 to fix these. 1.2.5 should be available shortly on [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22braintree%22) once it has synced.